# Read a netcdf file on an ftp server with python

Tags: python, ftp, netcdf

I need to access a netcdf file, which is stored on a remote ftp server. I could easily download it and read it from my local disk. But the files are very big and there are very many of them. So downloading them all would take about ten days. Since I only need a part of the data from the netcdf files, I am looking for a way to read the file without downloading it before.
I have tried working with ftplib, but that package seems to offer only functions to download the file. So I came to urllib.
I thought something like the following code would work, but it doesn't.

```
import urllib.request
from netCDF4 import Dataset

path = "Core/GLOBAL_REANALYSIS_PHYS_001_017/global-reanalysis-phys-001-017
        ...-ran-uk-orap5.0-gridt"
filename = "votemper_ORAP5.0_1m_197901_grid_T_02.nc"

req = urllib.request.Request("ftp:// username:pwd@rancmems.mercator-ocean.fr/"
      ...+path+"/"+filename)

fid = Dataset(req, 'r')
print(fid.variables.keys())
```

I get the error message "OSError: No such file or directory". So I don't have access to the netcdf file. 
Is there a way to solve the problem?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You can not do it without a special manager which is installed on remote web server where data is stored. FTP protocol does not allowed proportional downloading of desired part of file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought something like that. But just for clarification. This does also mean, that i cannot read the netcdf file directly on the remote server? If I could access the data without downloading it, I could than create a new netcdf file with the subset of the data I need. So I am not trying a direct download of a part of the data, just reading it.

Comment: Yep, you need to download file first

Comment: You can also set up OpenDAP or THREDDS server for partial downloading, if you need to do this often. THREDDS is actually rather easy to manage.